# Work with complex functions in mathematica 6

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How to use a correct function for arg, re and im in order to obtain correct wok on mathematica. For example 
When inputting

```
Simplify[D[r^2 Re[e^(i t) r]^2 ,r],r>0 && t>0]
```

One has

```
2 r^3 Cos[t] (Cos[t]+e^(i t) Re' [e^(i t) r])
```

But what is Re', how to avoid this nonexisting function?

Comment: Hello new user.  Visit http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ also.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that you intended `e` to be `E` and `i` to be `I`.

```
expr = Simplify[r^2 Re[E^(I t) r]^2, r > 0 && t > 0]

D[expr, r]
```

> ```
> r^4 Cos[t]^2
>
> 4 r^3 Cos[t]^2
> ```